# Creating ActiveMQ broker fails on subsequent tests with Service not found: 'META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/wireformat/default'

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have multiple unit tests of my camel routes in different test classes. The first test class runs fine, the subsequent ones fail with

```
Service not found:'META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/wireformat/default'
```

I want to test my JMS routes so I have to start a temporary activemq broker in my tests.

I already tried to destroy the broker resources I'm creating in the @BeforeClass method. However that doesn't seem to make a difference.

This is how I'm setting up the broker in my test classes:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    brokerSvc = new BrokerService();
    brokerSvc.setBrokerName("TestBroker");
    brokerSvc.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
    brokerSvc.start();
}
```

And this is how I tear it down after

```
@AfterClass
public static void teardownClass() throws Exception {
    brokerSvc.stop();
    brokerSvc.waitUntilStopped();
}
```

I expect that this releases the resources allocated so I can use the same methods in the subsequent tests to setup and tear down the temporary broker, but it just throws above error.

How can I safely create a temporary broker for each of my test classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if anyone actually uses camel anymore since the question was viewed a whopping 11 times in 5 days, but here's the answer anyways:

This is the correct setUp

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    brokerSvc = new BrokerService();
    brokerSvc.setBrokerName("TestBroker");
    brokerSvc.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
    brokerSvc.start();
}
```

This is the correct tearDown

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    brokerSvc.stop();
    brokerSvc = null;
}
```